# Call failed using Asterisk

Tags: configuration, sip, asterisk, ethernet, sip-server

I am trying on 2 PCs, First acts as sip server & client (has asterisk & twinkle installed) and the other as a client only(has twinkle only installed) . 
I try to make a call between them using Ethernet cable -No internet- so I established the wired connection and I gave each of them an address , I gave the 1st one with asterisk installed ip 192.168.0.1 & the 2nd one 192.168.0.2. Fist one has username 100 & 2nd one is 101.

I wrote in terminal "sudo asterisk -rvvvvvvv" then "sip reload" then "dialplan reload" then "sip set debug on" & I establish the wired connection so I find the 2 Twinkles on the 2 Pcs registered successfully to asterisk but when I try to make a call between them , Twinkle said that " call failed 404 not found " 
i think then the problem is in the extensions.conf but i can not figure out what is wrong, any one can help me .?
Here is the full output on terminal mediafire.com/?6g0uuhkai5vcahk

Also tell me if there is anything wrong in the file as I am beginner.

### Thanks in advance Here are the configuration files:

### sip.conf

[general]

bindport=5060

udpbindaddr=192.168.0.1:5060

allowguest=yes

disallow=all

allow=gsm

delayreject=yes

nochecksums=no

pedantic=no

srvlookup=yes

autodomain=yes

sipdebug = yes

domain=192.168.0.1

nat=no

notifyringing=yes

notifyhold=yes

register => 100:sarasara@192.168.0.1/internal-phones

register => 101:saadsaad@192.168.0.1/internal-phones

peer auth=100:sarasara@192.168.0.1

peer auth=101:saadsaad@192.168.0.1

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[192.168.0.1]

usereqphone = yes

nat=no

fromdomain=192.168.0.1

fromuser=100

secret=sarasara

username=100

context=internal-phones

authname=100

dtmfmode = rfc2833

canreinvite=yes

notifyringing=yes

notifyhold=yes

peer auth=100:sarasara@192.168.0.1

peer auth=101:saadsaad@192.168.0.1

disallow=all

allow=gsm

[100]

type=friend

context=internal-phones

secret=sarasara

nat=no

qualify=no

host=dynamic

dtmfmode = rfc2833

permit=192.168.0.1

[101]

type=friend

context=internal-phones

secret=saadsaad

qualify=no

host=dynamic

nat=no

dtmfmode = rfc2833

permit=192.168.0.1

---

### extensions.conf

[globals]

[general]

exten => 100,1,Dial(SIP/100,60)

exten => 101,1,Dial(SIP/101,60)

exten => s,1,hangup

[internal-phones]
exten => 100,1,Dial(SIP/100,60)

exten => 101,1,Dial(SIP/101,60)

exten => s,1,hangup

Comment: user "asterisk -r" to  see what it actualy do.If nothing shown,try also use sip set debug on/core set verbose 5 on that console. There are no any way answer your question based on info provided.

Comment: I wrote in terminal "sudo asterisk -rvvvvvvv" then "sip reload" then "dialplan reload" then "sip set debug on" & I establish the wired connection so I find the 2 Twinkles on the 2 Pcs registered to asterisk but when I try to make a call between them , Twinkle said that " call failed 404 not found "
 Here is the full output on terminal mediafire.com/?6g0uuhkai5vcahk

Comment: sorry, this site is not asterisk mailing list nor some debug source. very likly you missed something with context. If you not able read books, you have hire expert.

Answer (score 0):

Enable SIP debugging (`sip set debug on`) to view the SIP response for the call. (`503`, `403` or `404` ?). 
Also, make sure your soft-phone is listening on an udp port other than 5060, which will conflict with asterisk.

Comment: I wrote in terminal "sudo asterisk -rvvvvvvv" then "sip reload" then "dialplan reload" then "sip set debug on" & I establish the wired connection so I find the 2 Twinkles on the 2 Pcs registered to asterisk but when I try to make a call between them , Twinkle said that " call failed 404 not found " 
Here is the full output on terminal

https://www.mediafire.com/?6g0uuhkai5vcahk